# Google Sheet custom function: Pass cell address as argument

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am creating a custom function `Print(arg)` and calling this function from my google sheet like `Print(A4)`, `Print(B12)` etc.. I want to print referenced cell itself like A4 or B12 instead of values coming from that cell, any help ?

I tried `Logger.log(A4)` but here it prints the value at A4, but I need to print "A4" itself

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'm not gonna ask you why you want this as you might have some reason, but by default, the value of the cell is being passed when used in a custom function. So if you want to use it like `=print(A4)` and expect `print` custom function to return `"A4"` as string, that would be impossible.

Although you can have an alternative option of using `onEdit` trigger to manually manipulate your data once it detects you are using the pattern `=print(cellRef)` (case insensitive) and it will return `cellRef`.

#### Script:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var match = /=print\(([^)]+)\)/i.exec(e.value)[1];
  if (match != null)
    e.range.setValue(match);
}
```

#### Output:

[image: output]

#### Note:

- As you see in the output above, it will replace `=print(cellRef)` and the cell will contain the `cellRef` as string instead.
- To avoid seeing an error of `#NAME?`, have a placeholder function for `print` with nothing on it so it will show `Loading...` instead while waiting for the `onEdit` to finish.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var match = /=print\(([^)]+)\)/i.exec(e.value)[1];
  if (match != null)
    e.range.setValue(match);
}
// Placeholder print function to avoid #NAME? error while waiting for onEdit
function print() {
}
```

[image: output2]

You can also use sheet functions to get the reference, that would be via using `cell` with a little manipulation.

```
=regexreplace(cell("address", A4), "\$", "")
```

[image: output]

Or combine `cell` with your `print` function

```
=print(cell("address", A4))
```

```
function print(cellRef) {
  return cellRef.replaceAll("\$", "");
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your can do it with built-it formula

```
=SUBSTITUTE(CELL("address", A4),"$",)
```